# Where do you find doctor Domsky

Tags: full-of-stars

I am stuck in my 5th journey at the moment. I got blue sector to level 2, now I need to find doctor Domsky for level 3. I used the green orbs to find out his position but I don't know how to get to him.

I will add a picture of the map, If anyone knows how to get to them it would be great. He is somewhere between the station and the other points, I don't know what sequence of conversations I need to get to his destination.

[image: doctor domsky's location( shown but no route)]

Answer (score 1):

After the colony ask you to bring a doctor, when you reach the Blue Sector again, you will find a free hint that where he could be. This give you a very good idea about his exact location. Or you can spend 40 rare iridium particle to locate it on the map.

Spoiler lvl1:
 Tortuga

Lvl2 spoiler:
When you reach the tortuga station, talk about slavery. You will see a third option to ask whereabouts of Dr. Domsky.

Spoiler level 3:
After you gain the information, another location will be revealed on map. At that station you'll find him. 3 command points or 10 rare iridium particle will convince him to join your crew.

Spoiler level 4:
If your passenger capacity is above " full capacity minus 5(or 6)", your chance to bring him to onboard with 3 command point will be low. But you can always persuade him with 10 rare iridium particle in the end.

P.S: I tried to write like UHS hint system to not spoil the suprises.

Answer (score 0):

The slave traders that you can see before QCOS tell you that they sold Domsky to "the pirates".  I'd assume this means in Tortuga.  Hope you are able to find him.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the Blue Sector up in levels you'll have a chance to see where he is. I think it cost me 40 Idium crystals to see. He is located just north of Tortuga station. When you are at Tortuga station ask to trade slaves. Instead of the regular buy/sell slaves you'll be able to buy information about the Dr.'s whereabouts. That will open up a new Nav point. Then you fly to get him. You'll have to complete a dialogue and have some Idium ready to get him to come with you.

Answer (score 0):

First go to the slave destination. That is where you actually find word that the pirates have Domsky. Then you'll have an option in Tortuga to ask about Domsky.